# Unable to create a database with RedisSearch Module in Rocky OS 8

Tags: linux, database, redis

I have a Redis Enterprise running with 3 nodes. The DB core seems to work fine.
They only thing In an able to do is to create a DB Including Redis Search module.
Redis version is 7.2 and Redis Search is 2.4.4 Pretty much their latest stuff

Here is what  get when I try to add the module through the console or comman line

"Why do I get combination of OS rocky8 and arch x86_64 of node 3 is not supported by module RediSearch 2. Module will not be added to the database"

Rocky Linux * is officially supported by Redis Labs using an Enterprise Cluster

Reinstalled Redis Seach module, tried older versions as well
Tried to compile from source but it throws errors dude to Python incompatibility between Redis and newer Python

Im able to remove and add compatible version of any modules throgu the admin interface, im not able to create a database including a module

Answer (score 1):

We at Redis found and solved a bug that has these exact symptoms you're describing. The release with the fix has been published: https://docs.redis.com/latest/rs/release-notes/rs-7-2-4-releases/rs-7-2-4-64/ (fixes RS107909)